# android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView at onCreateView of the fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to work on a material design project where I am creating a List layout.
The error is as followed:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView at (package).ListContentFragment.onCreateView
```

the OnCreateView Code of the fragment class is as followed:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);
    ContentAdapter adapter = new ContentAdapter(recyclerView.getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    return recyclerView;
```

The XML file of the fragment is as followed:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:padding="@dimen/md_keylines"> 

.....

</RelativeLayout>
```

the complete code can be found at[Code on github](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-design-library/blob/master/4-RecyclerView/src/main/java/com.example.android.materialdesigncodelab/ListContentFragment.java)

Comment: `android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` So, you basically want to convert an apple pie into a banana...

Comment: the apple pie was converted to banana at : [link](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-design-library/blob/master/4-RecyclerView/src/main/java/com.example.android.materialdesigncodelab/ListContentFragment.java)

Comment: No, it was not converted. They didn't even try to. Or they would get the same error.

Comment: Sorry i should have asked them first if they had run the code before posting it on github and google is using it in their tutorials

Comment: put adapter code as well

Comment: @Rotwang can you tell me the solution for it?

Comment: @SuryaPrakashKushawah please visit this link [Code](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-design-library/blob/master/4-RecyclerView/src/main/java/com.example.android.materialdesigncodelab/ListContentFragment.java)

Comment: I should **guess** your current code. But my crystal ball is on repairs...

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

A layout manager positions item views inside a RecyclerView and determines when to reuse item views that are no longer visible to the user.

```
ContentAdapter adapter = new ContentAdapter(recyclerView.getContext());

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: i just run your solution but its still the same. I am getting the same old error